# Tableview within a tableview or autolayout nightmare

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

Looking for advice from more seasoned IOS dev's. I'm building with swift and autolayout storyboards. I have a cell within a table view that displays a picture and comments.

[image: tableview within tableview]

My problem is that any picture can have zero to several comments. I would like to limit it to two but I am now looking at having a tableview within a tableview cell. My other approach was to just add two comments and set the height to zero if comments for that picture have not been made yet. I started down the tableview within tableview (tableview inception) approach but shifted thinking that Apples autolayout would just pull everything in tight. Sadly `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` Turned out to be a layout nightmare and never did work right inspite of my carefully placed constraints. Am I missing a third obvious option. What would be your approach?

Comment: Have you considered using two different types of cells in one tableView? One for the photo and second for as many comments as there might be i.e.  One 1 `PhotoTableViewCell` and three `CommentTableViewCell` following each other being populated by one object of PhotoWithComments class?

Comment: Sometimes you stare at something long enough you miss the obvious. Got some reasons I was thinking that a cell had to embedded in a table view but never really considered that you could have multiple cells. Seems obvious now. I will give it a try, thank you very much.

Comment: No problem! Hope it works out for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use view based `NSTableView` with 2 `NSTableCellView`.

- PhotoWithComments `NSTableCellView`
- WithoutComment `NSTableCellView`

I think using view based `NSTableView` would be easy then cell based `NSTableView` for your problem.